# Oracle reports SMTP change

Tags: windows-server-2008, oracle, oracle-11g

We recently migrated our SMTP address from `smtp.old.example` to `smtp.new.example`, this caused our Oracle reports server to stop sending emails which was expected.

I have updated the `<pluginParam name="mailServer" value="smtp.new.example"/>` values in `rwbuilder.conf` and `rwserver.conf`(found by using windows file search) and rebooted the server.

Emails however are still not being sent despite the reports running succesfully and generating the PDFs, I am calling reports using the format:

`http://ourserver:9002/reports/rwservlet?server=ReportsServer&report=c:\Oracle\Middleware\as_1\forms\test\test.rdf&desformat=pdf&destype=mail&userid=****/****@****&paramform=no&desname=<RecipientEmail>&subject=test&from=<SenderEmail>&report_filename=test`

I have created a small C# application to ensure that emails can be sent to and from the server itself to both internal and external email addresses which works fine. I feel like I am missing a configuration file or step somewhere?

I have also added (temporarily) `smtp.old.example` to the HOST file pointing to the IP of `smtp.new.example`, however this has not helped either.

Any insight, ideas or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

We are running on Windows Server 2008 SP2 with Oracle reports 11.1.1.1.0